# Confusion matrices for two lists of raster objects

Tags: raster, r, confusion-matrix

I have two lists of raster objects. One contains validation plots and the other contains results from a random forest binary classification of those plots.  I would like to loop through both lists with `caret::confusionMatrix` to assess accuracy of the classifier. However, some rasters only have one class present, and `caret::confusionMatrix` returns the

> Error: there must be at least two levels in the data.

Comment: How are you casting the rasters to factors for `confusionMatrix`? Supply a `levels` argument to `factor` giving all the possible levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample data - you should make something like this in your question to illustrate:

```
> r1 = raster(matrix(sample(1:3,25,TRUE),5,5))
> r2 = raster(matrix(sample(1:3,25,TRUE),5,5))
```

Confusion matrix of a raster is an error:

```
> confusionMatrix(r1,r2)
Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
```

So convert to a factor **with the same levels**:

```
> confusionMatrix(factor(r1[],levels=1:3),factor(r2[],levels=1:3))
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction 1 2 3
         1 5 1 2
         2 3 5 5
         3 3 0 1
```

Then if one of your rasters is lacking levels, then it still works:

```
> r3 = raster(matrix(1,5,5))
> confusionMatrix(factor(r1[],levels=1:3),factor(r3[],levels=1:3))
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  1  2  3
         1  8  0  0
         2 13  0  0
         3  4  0  0
```

The only condition here is that you have to know all the possible values in advance. If a sudden "42" sneaks in somewhere then it will break. Get all unique values in your rasters beforehand and then create factors with that.